# React MUI Checkbox set checked on false value

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, material-ui

I am having this problem with React MUI - Checkbox component. I have the site where I have the checkbox with handler targeting to the REST API endpoint that sets the boolean flag for the user in the database on POST request and returns the boolean value for the logged user.

Backend code:

```py
# Models
class Client(models.Model):

    all_submitted = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False)
```

```py
# Views
@api_view(["POST", "GET"])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def all_submitted(request):
    current_client = request.user.client

    if request.method == "GET":
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK, data={
            "submitted": current_client.all_submitted
        })

    elif request.method == "POST":
        checked = request.data['checked']

        if type(checked) == bool:
            with transaction.atomic():
                current_client.all_submitted = checked
                current_client.save()


        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK, data={
            "submitted": current_client.all_submitted
        })
```

and the client code:

```js
const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

const handleChange = (event) => {
        api.post("/client/files", {checked: event.target.checked}).then((response) => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                setChecked(response.data.allEvidenceSubmitted);
            }
        })
    };

useEffect(() => {
     api.get("/client/files").then((response) => {
          if (response.status === 200) {
             setChecked(response.data.allEvidenceSubmitted);
            }
        });
    }, ["checked"])


<FormGroup>
  <FormControlLabel labelPlacement="bottom"
                    control={<Checkbox
                    checked={checked}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    inputProps={{'aria-label': 'controlled'}}
                    />}
    label={t("checkbox", "I confirm that the documents have been completely uploaded.", {ns: "evidence"})}/>
</FormGroup>
```

Now the problem is that when the value is supposed to be false, then on page refresh, even if the `false` value is returned, the checkbox gets checked.

Does anyone have some clue about this?

Thank you for any hints.

Comment: Can you update your question with the console logged values of `response.status` and `response.data.allEvidenceSubmitted` . Side note, you're passing a string literal to the dependency array. So your `useEffect` will not trigger on check value changed. I assume you only want that to run on page load so you can leave the dependency array empty

Comment: @RyanZeelie response status is always 200, and when the response is false, then it gets checked anyway.

Comment: Is the issue still not resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Are you importing `import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';`
I ran into something similar and realized that I had imported the Checkbox icon instead.